# Opening file from a Fileshare-system with python

Tags: python, pandas

im trying to open a file from a Filesharing-System of our company. Here is the Code of the script:

```
import sys
import xlrd
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import time
from os import *

#hvl_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
save_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="C:/", defaultextension=".xlsx")


t1 = time.clock()
hvl = pd.read_csv('\\-----Berichte_SQL\HVL.csv', sep='|', encoding='latin1', low_memory=False)
hvl.to_excel(save_path, index=False)
t2 = time.clock()
t_ges = t2 - t1
print(t_ges)
```

You can see the file_path is: \-----\Berichte_SQL\HVL.csv

When i start the script i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/-----/Desktop/PROJEKTE/[INPROGRESS] AUSWERTUNG COIN + HVL/hvl_convert.py", line 13, in <module>
    hvl = pd.read_csv('------\Berichte_SQL\HVL.csv', sep='|', encoding='latin1', low_memory=False)
  File "C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Downloaded Apps\Winpython\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 474, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Downloaded Apps\Winpython\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 250, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Downloaded Apps\Winpython\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 566, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\------------\AppData\Local\Downloaded Apps\Winpython\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 705, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\----------\AppData\Local\Downloaded Apps\Winpython\python-3.4.3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1072, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 350, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:3187)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 594, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:5930)
OSError: File b'----------\\Berichte_SQL\\HVL.csv' does not exist
```

So my question is if there is a problem with the path or its a point of missing permissions. Do you have any ideas?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Now i tried to open the file:

```
f = open('\\---------\Berichte_SQL\HVL.csv','w')
```

After trying to open the file with open i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/--------ROJEKTE/[INPROGRESS] AUSWERTUNG COIN + HVL/hvl_convert.py", line 13, in <module>
    f = open('\\---------------\Berichte_SQL\HVL.csv','w')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: that didnt work! i get the same error like i have with the backslashes

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: no that didnt work... get the missing data error...

Comment: are you sure the file exists? does it work even using `open` rather than `read_csv` as this maybe a permissions or no access problem

Comment: and yes im sure the file exists i open it every day manually

Comment: can you edit your question to show the new code and the new error with stacktrace?

Comment: tried that... didnt work! the i get the TypeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with UNC strings or Windows strings in general it is better to declare constant strings with the `r` (raw) prefix:

```
pd.read_csv(r'\\Q4DEE1SYVFS.ffm ...')
```

not doing that result in some chars to be interpreted:

```
print("foo\test")
```

yields:

```
foo est   (tabulation has been inserted)
```

Same goes for many lowercase chars (`\t,\n,\v,\b,\x ...).

Double antislashes means "escape the antislash" and is converted a single backslash.

```
print('\\ddd')
```

yields:

```
\ddd
```

thus your path is incorrect.

But there's more here. You shouldn't get `expected int found str` errors. So I found out the problem in one of your comments: there are some invisible chars causing trouble. I pasted the path from your comments in pyscripter and assigned it to a variable and go this:

```
>>> z=r"\\Q4DEE1SYVFS.ffm.t-systems.com\pasm$\Berichte_SQL\HVL‌​.csv"
>>> z
'\\\\Q4DEE1SYVFS.ffm.t-systems.com\\pasm$\\Berichte_SQL\\HVL\xe2\x80\x8c\xe2\x80\x8b.csv'
```

Just rewrite the last part of your string and it will work.

PS: notepad++ was unable to see the weird chars. I heard that SciTe had a tendency to let those pass too. Pyscripter sees them.